# Azure AD: I need to change a Company wide setting, but apparently that's impossible?

Tags: azure, powershell

I need to change a setting in Azure to allow for Email Verification. MS documentation states that I have to get into azure's powershell and run Set-MsolCompanySettings -AllowEmailVerifiedUsers. I found this, however, to be apparently impossible?

In order to do this, I have to use before: Connect-MsolService, which gives me this error:

> Connect-MsolService: Could not load file or assembly
> 'System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file
> specified.

And from what I read, Azure's Powershell does not allow for this?? How am I supposed to run that command?

Thanks in advance, any clue is welcome at this point

Answer (score 0):

We have did a repro in our local environment, below statements are based on the repro analysis.
I have tried connecting to msolservice & successfully  enabled the company setting " AllowEmailVerifiedUsers" in my local machine that is running with PowerShell version 5.1

```
Set-MsolCompanySettings -AllowEmailVerifiedUsers $true
```

Here is the output

[image]

I have tried running the same company  setting cmdlet in PowerShell core version 7 it is failing with same error that you have mentioned above.

[image]

Based on this [GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16052) , we understood that currently MSOnline module version v1 is too old and it is not supported in PowerShell core 7.

We would suggest you use the PowerShell version 5.1 to enable company setting using MsolOnline module.